# How to format string data return from API to use react-csv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

- I have an issue with data when use react-csv I got data return from
  api with format like below.
- I want to parse to header, data to use in
  react-csv?

  ```
   id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address
   1,Sibby,Gehrels,sgehrels0@earthlink.net,Female,202.163.188.135
   2,Karin,Mulran,kmulran1@techcrunch.com,Female,160.131.170.201
   3,Silvan,Ablett,sablett2@blogger.com,Male,208.242.3.221

  const headers = [
   { label: "First Name", key: "firstName" },
   { label: "Last Name", key: "lastName" },
   { label: "Email", key: "email" },
   { label: "Age", key: "age" }
  ];

   const data = [
   { firstName: "Warren", lastName: "Morrow", email: "sokyt@mailinator.com", age: "36" },
   { firstName: "Gwendolyn", lastName: "Galloway", email: "weciz@mailinator.com", age: "76" },
   { firstName: "Astra", lastName: "Wyatt", email: "quvyn@mailinator.com", age: "57" },
   { firstName: "Jasmine", lastName: "Wong", email: "toxazoc@mailinator.com", age: "42" },
   { firstName: "Brooke", lastName: "Mcconnell", email: "vyry@mailinator.com", age: "56" },
   { firstName: "Christen", lastName: "Haney", email: "pagevolal@mailinator.com", age: "23" },
   ];





   <CSVLink
   headers={header}
   data={data}
   separator=";"
   asyncOnClick={true}
   onClick={handleOnclick}
   >
   <button>DownLoad CSV</button>
   </CSVLink>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataFromApi = `id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address
1,Sibby,Gehrels,sgehrels0@earthlink.net,Female,202.163.188.135
2,Karin,Mulran,kmulran1@techcrunch.com,Female,160.131.170.201
3,Silvan,Ablett,sablett2@blogger.com,Male,208.242.3.221`;

const dataByLines = dataFromApi.split('\n');

const headers = dataByLines[0].split(',').map((value) => ({
  label: value, key: value,
}));
console.log(headers);

let data = [];

// dataByLines[0] are headers
for (let i = 1; i < dataByLines.length; i++) {
  const columns = dataByLines[i].split(',');
  let oneOfData = {};

  for (let j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names
    oneOfData = { ...oneOfData, [headers[j].label]: columns[j] };
  }

  data = data.concat(oneOfData);
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).